# NDK libjpeg-turbo shared library build faild with armeabi

Tags: android, android-ndk, libjpeg-turbo

I use sorccu's Github code to build shared library by just editing the .mk file last line to "include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)".
https://github.com/openstf/android-libjpeg-turbo
But it failed with:

```
    .......
    [armeabi] Compile thumb  : sohucs-jpeg <= transupp.c
    [armeabi] Compile thumb  : sohucs-jpeg <= jdatadst-tj.c
    [armeabi] Compile thumb  : sohucs-jpeg <= jdatasrc-tj.c
    [armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libsohucs-jpeg.so
    D:/eclipse/workspace/HelloNeon/jni/vendor/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo-1.4.1/jccolor.c:603: error: undefined reference to 'jsimd_can_rgb_gray'
    D:/eclipse/workspace/HelloNeon/jni/vendor/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo-1.4.1/jccolor.c:658: error: undefined reference to 'jsimd_can_rgb_ycc'
    .......
```

My ndk-build version is r10e, and I use eclipse 4.5.1 MARS, win7.
The other platform: armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a-hard arm64-v8a x86 x86_64, build fine, without error.

I have read the issue of sorccu github. It is not my problem. https://github.com/openstf/android-libjpeg-turbo/issues/1
I aim to build share library of libjpeg-turbo of armabi.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: The answer can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/openstf/android-libjpeg-turbo/issues/1#issuecomment-149809966). **libjpeg-turbo** whole *raison d'etre* is to provide hardware acceleration to **libjpeg**. There is no hardware acceleration on **armeabi**, therefore build for **armeabi** is not supported.

Comment: At any rate, it is probably not worth the effort to support **armeabi**. As of 12/26/2015, the [official statistics page](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) shows less than 3.5% of all Android devices running versions below Ice Cream Sandwich, which are potentially capable to run on ARM v6.

Comment: Is there a way to build a shared libjpeg-turbo lib which compatible with **armeabi** ?  No need to have neon acceleration.

Comment: **a)** There is zero advantage of libjpeg-turbo for armeabi without NEON as compared to libjpeg. **b)** Yes, you can build it without NEON for armeabi, the instructions at https://wiki.linaro.org/BenjaminGaignard/libjpeg-turboAndSkia will work